# It seems I have an rpath issue Installing pygame on OSX El Capitan 10.11

Tags: python, macos, pygame, sdl, osx-elcapitan

I downloaded the latest pygame 1.9.1 source. First I set the following environment variables:

```
export CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
export CFLAGS='-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -I/opt/X11/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64'
export LDFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
```

Then, in the SDL.framework Headers I copied them all into a subfolder called SDL to deal with some issues in hard paths in the pygame source. Setting those things up seemed to get me to the point of building. And, installation ran fine. However, when I try to import pygame I get the following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pygame/base.so
  Reason: image not found
```

There's definitely an SDL executable in the indicated location, assuming rpath is correct. However, it may be incorrect, how does on check rpath.

Answer (score 2):

I had no problem installing following the procedure described here:
http://kidscancode.org/blog/2015/09/pygame_install/

While this uses homebrew to install all of the libraries, if you have them, you should be able to install pygame using:

```
$ pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

However, be aware that Pygame has a number of issues under El Capitan, as described here:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated

The worst one is that graphics do not render properly.  This was not the case under Yosemite.

EDIT:

It seems that this may be an SDL issue rather than a Pygame issue, based on the discussion here:
[Rendering Glitch on Mac OSX El Capitan with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115482/rendering-glitch-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-with-opengl)

I am going to see if I can test downgrading SDL_image from 1.2.12 to 1.2.10 to confirm.

Comment: We have a lot of python 2 code that won't be updated anytime soon because we have other package dependencies that are python 2 so I've updated my question to be more specific for that. Nevertheless, I'd very much like to see your question update after the SDL_image test.

Comment: Yes, since it's an issue with SDL_image, the graphics issues are there in Python 2 as well (just tried it out).  No luck yet on the downgrade test, as it's leading me into dependency issues.  May have to try on a fresh copy of  El Cap when I have a little more time.

Answer (score 2):

1) First, if you're using El Capitan, you need to add root access to /usr/local:

```
sudo su
chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

2) Then install homebrew: http://brew.sh/ (install ruby, if you dont have it)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

3) After that, install pygame using homebrew:

```
sudo brew install homebrew/python/pygame
```

Worked for me :)