# Python3 and Pygame on OS X. Images with no color

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-elcapitan, python-3.5

Just installed python3 and pygame on os x el capitan via HomeBrew.
Version: Python 3.5.1

However when try to add a background image to my game it has no colors inside the game. Some images have colors, but might have some weird colored pixels.

Here is the result from the game:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaD8D.jpg

And here are the original images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4xG.jpg

Wondering if it might be that I have a too new version of python3 for pygame to run as intended.

But can't find out how to install a older version of python3 via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are several problems with El Capitan and certain versions of SDL, which is the library pygame uses under the hood for loading and displaying graphics. Some threads suggest fixing it by downgrading the currently provided version of SDL. pygame should soon update to the newest version which should also solve the problems.

See here about the SDL bug:
[Rendering Glitch on Mac OSX El Capitan with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115482/rendering-glitch-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-with-opengl)

See here about the pygame link to this bug:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing this: Not sure if the first code block is nessesarry.
Might work with just the last part.

```
sudo bash
curl -O https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL_image-1.2.10.tar.gz
tar zxvf SDL_image-1.2.10.tar.gz
cd SDL_image-1.2.10
./configure
make
make install
```

Restart terminal and:

```
brew remove sdl_image
export SDL_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/sdl-config
brew install sdl_image
```